# React Hide/Show Component by Key

Tags: reactjs

n React Js I have rendered a lot of Photos component.

```
class PhotoList extends Component {
render() {
    return (

        <div className="content">           
            { _.map(this.props.photos, function(photo) { return ([<Photo key={photo.Id} data={photo} />, ' ']); }) }
        </div>
    );
}};


class Photo extends Component {
selectPhoto() {

}
EditPhoto() {

}
DetachPhoto() {

}
stopPropagation(e) {

}

dragStart() {

}

render () {
    var tooltip = (
        <Tooltip>
            <div className="text-nowrap">
                <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> {createdAt} / {this.props.data.CreatedBy}
                <br />
                <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> {modifiedAt} / {this.props.data.ModifiedBy}
            </div>
        </Tooltip>
    );
    return (
        <div onClick={this.selectPhoto.bind(this)} draggable='true' onDragStart={this.dragStart.bind(this)} className={classNames('thumbnail', { selected: this.props.photo.Selected })}>
            <div className="photo">
                <span className="helper"></span>
                <img src={'' + this.props.data.PId + '.jpg'} />
                <ul className="list-inline photo-toolbar" onClick={this.stopPropagation.bind(this)}>
                    <li><span title="Edit" className="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" onClick={this.EditPhoto.bind(this)}></span></li>
                    <li><span title="Detach" className="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" onClick={this.DetachPhoto.bind(this)}></span></li>
                    <li>
                        <OverlayTrigger placement='bottom' overlay={tooltip}>
                            <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-tag" />
                        </OverlayTrigger>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href={'https:www.fgdfg/' + this.props.data.PId + '.jpg' } target="_blank"><span title="Full size" className="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-full"></span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

};

I want to hide Photo component after a click on it and show component after click a button.

I tried use React.unmountComponentAtNode() function, but I don't know how to select Photo compontnet with proper Key.

Comment: can you please add Photo component code here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have prepared one Demo for you to achieve your goal you can refer below mentioned URL
http://plnkr.co/edit/wFUtCfOYqTYfUFTn1sBk?p=preview

```
 var HideMe=React.createClass({
  Hide:function(event)
  {
    var Selected=$(event.target)[0].id;
     $("#"+Selected).removeClass('show');
    $("#"+Selected).addClass('hide');
  },
  Show:function(event)
  {
    var Selected=$(event.target)[0].id;
     $("#"+Selected).removeClass('hide');
    $("#"+Selected).addClass('show');
  },
  render:function()
  {
    return(
      <div>
      <div>
       <span id="1" onClick={this.Hide}>Click me to Hide</span>
        <input type="button" id="1" value="Show" onClick={this.Show}/>
      </div>
     <div>
      <span id="2" onClick={this.Hide}>Click me to Hide</span>
        <input type="button" id="2" value="Show" onClick={this.Show} />
     </div>
      </div>

      )
  }
});
React.render(
  <HideMe />,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```